# How do write snmptrapd configuration file?

Tags: logging, centos, snmp, snmptrapd

I need snmptrapd configuration file, ı does not find any configuration file. If ı run `"snmptrapd -Le -A -Lf /var/log/snmptrapd.log`" command from commandline,  snmptrapd process is running. And ı try this `snmptrapd -Le -A -Lf /var/log/snmptrapd.log --`install , but service not running or create.
How ı write manually `snmptrapd.conf`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Linux, If you are using net-snmp package. You can find the configuration files at `/etc/snmp/snmptrapd,conf`.
According to the [NET-SNMP man page](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmp_config.html), the tool looks for the configuration of snmp and snmptrapd in the following directories in order:

```
ROOTDIR/etc/snmp, ROOTDIR/usr/share/snmp, ROOTDIR/usr/lib/snmp, and $HOME/.snmp
```

You can also check the configuration directory by executing.

```
sudo net-snmp-config --snmpconfpath
```

You can create the snmptrapd.conf file in the location and start adding configuration to it.

For testing purposes, you can provide the parameter '-c' in `snmptrapd` command to specify config file location.

```
# eg. sudo snmptrapd -f -C -c snmptrapd.conf -Le -m ALL
sudo snmptrapd -f -C -c <config file location> -Le -m ALL
```

There are different SNMP versions (snmp v1, snmp v2 and snmp v3) which can be used for sending/receiving traps.

SNMP v1 is the least secure (also used less), snmp v2 uses 'community string' as a key for authentication and snmp v3 is the most secure till now which has 'User based'(USM) and 'TLS/DTLS based'(TSM) authentication.

For SNMP v2, the very basic configuration to receive a trap is as follow

```
# SNMP v2 configuration

# Access control
# Eg: authCommunity log,execute,net public
authCommunity log <community-string>
```

After saving this configuration and restart snmptrapd server. You can try this command from your system to send the trap.

```
snmptrap -v2c -c public 127.0.0.1 '' 1.3.6.1.4.1.33095.0.1000 1.3.6.1.4.1.33095.0.1000 s "This is my first snmp trap."
```

You can add more options listed in [snmptrapd.conf doc](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmptrapd.conf.html).

For SNMP v3(USM), You can use the following configuration for receiving traps.

```
# SNMPv3 config with AuthPriv security level.

# Create a user for authentication
# Eg. createUser snmptestuser SHA shapassword AES aespassword
createUser <username> <AuthProtocol> <authpass> <PrivProtocol> <privpass>

# Access control
# Eg. authuser log,execute,net snmptestuser
authuser log <username>
```

Restart snmptrapd server and run the following to command to send the trap

```
snmptrap -Ci -v 3 -a SHA -A shapassword -x AES -X aespassword -l authPriv -u snmptestuser 127.0.0.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.33095.0.1000 1.3.6.1.4.1.33095.0.1000 s "This is my first snmp v3 trap."
```

You can refer to this [doc](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/TUT:Configuring_snmptrapd_to_receive_SNMPv3_notifications) for snmp v3 configuration.

I faced some problem while receiving the traps because of firewall, so make sure the firewall is configured properly or disable it completely if you want to test the initial configuration.